# Javafx smooth change speed of audio without interrupting playback

Tags: performance, javafx, media, playback

What's the best way to change the playback speed of an mp3 file, going gradually from 1.0 to 1.5 without interrupts of the sound, nor clear steps of increases being noticed by the listener?
I played around with the setRate, but I don't get things working smoothly.

```
public class AudioSyncTest extends Application {

private String song;
private Media songSound;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

Pane pane = new Pane();

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

 song = "/audio/I love the rain.mp3";
    songSound = new Media((getClass().getResource(song).toString()));
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(songSound);
    mediaPlayer.seek(Duration.ZERO);
    mediaPlayer.setRate(1);
    mediaPlayer.play();

    Button b = new Button("Speed up smoothly..");
    b.setOnAction(actionEvent ->
    {
        backgroundTask();
    });
    pane.getChildren().add(b);

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 280, 200);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

I tried with a background task... but no luck there either.

```
 public void backgroundTask() {
    Task<Void> task = new Task<>() {
        double currentSpeed = 1;
        double increment = 0.01;

        @Override
        public Void call() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    currentSpeed+= increment;
                    mediaPlayer.setRate(currentSpeed);
                    System.out.println("incremented: " + currentSpeed);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            //mediaPlayer.setRate(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(0.5, 1.5));
            return null;
        }
    };
    new Thread(task).start();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Kind regards,
Maarten

Comment: Use a `Timeline`?

Comment: @Slaw If you mean something like this:  `KeyValue speedStartValue = new KeyValue(mediaPlayer.rateProperty(), 1);
            KeyFrame keyFrame1 = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(0), speedStartValue);
            KeyValue speedEndValue = new KeyValue(mediaPlayer.rateProperty(), 1.5);
            KeyFrame keyFrame2 = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(2000), speedEndValue);
            timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(keyFrame1,keyFrame2);
            timeline.play();` . That didn't work. It pauses the song, and jumps 2s later to the 1.5 value.